# Voltage Spikes in AC voltage Controller

Tags: voltage, ac

[image: AC Voltage Controller Circuit] 
The diagram above shows my circuit. It is actually an AC Voltage Controller with PWM controlling the output voltage and a 1:2 transformer stepping it up to 230V. A 1.8uF capacitor is used as a filter which works fine to quite an extent.

The problem here is that the output voltage when fed back to the controller via a step down transformer and a voltage divider to bring voltage within safe limits of controller and an offset circuit (since controller doesn't bear negative voltages, contains a lot of spikes although there is no such spike at the load.

ADC waveform is given below

[image: ADC waveform]

I have tried changing the step down transformer, ADC circuit components, MOSFET and optocoupler but noise/spikes is still there and gets even worse some times.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Ha ha.... Yes, you forgot yr question..!!

Comment: Question is simple. Why there are spikes? and how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, assuming your question is about why the spikes are there and how to get rid it off...

If zero voltage switching is not used to synchronize the MOSFET switching with zero crossing of the rectified AC, switching occurs at random interval causing very high dV/dT and it generates tons of harmonics which adds up to the fundamental. Even if zvs is used, the MOSFET will have to cut off at non zero interval of the AC cycle since it follows the pwm signal from the controller. However, probably the severity of the harmonics could be reduced with zvs.

The only way to reduce this spikes is to employ snubber caps together with choke filters. Put the cap across the transformer primary just after a choke input filter. Caps may need resistor in series with them to prevent them from overheating.

Comment: Thank you @soosai. You mean a cap in parallel with transformer primary and an inductor just before this cap in series? Is that right?

Comment: Yes... That's right .